# Uploading a Python package to PyPI with GitHub repos in the `setup.py`

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I would like to publish a Python package on PyPI, but some of the packages in the `setup.py` are GitHub repositories (there are no PyPI packages for them available). Is there any way I can publish a PyPI package in this scenario? What is the recommended way to address this?

I tried making a PyPI package but only got it to succeed if I only used PyPI packages.

Comment: Relevant discussion: [*install_requires vs requirements files*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/). -- So the recommended way is to document clearly how to install the dependencies (from GitHub repositories), and provide an example of `requirements.txt` file.